# Exclude category on query_post custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I need to exclude a category from showing up posts.
I registered the taxonomy: portfolio-category
and added a category: accessories (cat ID 19) under portfolio-category

How do I exclude posts from accessories category from showing up?
I tried: `'category' => -19,` but it didn't work
here's my code:

```
        <?php
                $args=array(
                    'post_type'         => 'items',
                    'post_status'       => 'publish',
                    'showposts'         => intval( get_anolox_option_by('an_homep_count', 3) ),
                    'caller_get_posts'  => 1,
                    'category'          => -19,
                    'paged'             => $paged,
                );
                query_posts($args);

                $end = array(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45);

                $i = 0;
                while (have_posts()): the_post();
                global $post;
                $i++;
            ?>

    MY CODE HERE, NO NEED TO SHOW SINCE IT'S VERY LONG



            <?php endwhile; ?>          
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

edit// I tried this code, but still it didn't work:

```
    <?php
                $args=array(
                    'post_type'         => 'items',
                    'post_status'       => 'publish',
                    'showposts'         => intval( get_anolox_option_by('an_homep_count', 3) ),
                    'caller_get_posts'  => 1,

                    'paged'             => $paged,
                    'tax_query'          => array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category',
                        'terms' => 'accessories',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'operator' => 'NOT IN')
                );
                query_posts($args);
```

Comment: The issue is about array nesting like **clifgriffin** said.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9829059/2770718

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'=>'items',
        'order'=>'ASC',
        'posts_per_page'=>3
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => 19,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            ),
        )
));
query_posts($args);
```

**items= custom post type**

**portfolio-category = my custom taxonomy**

```
for multiple category exclude use  'terms' => array( '19,20' ),
```

Comment: This ought to be the green answer. It just now worked perfectly for me and saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

The `category` argument is meant for the built in category taxonomy.  Change your `$args` like so to reference your custom taxonomy:

```
$args=array(
    'post_type'          => 'items',
    'portfolio-category' => 'accessories',
    'post_status'        => 'publish',
    'showposts'          => intval( get_anolox_option_by('an_homep_count', 3)),
    'paged'              => $paged
);
```

This assumes the following:

1. You've got a custom post type called `items`.
2. The `portfolio-category` taxonomy is registered to it.
3. `accessories` is added to the `portfolio-category` taxonomy.

*Update:* Whoops...getting late.  To answer OP's actual question of how to exclude the `accessories` portfolio category (rather than include it as the above does), you can use the [tax_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) argument.  Code would be as follows to exclude `accessories`:

```
$args=array(
    'post_type'          => 'items'
    'post_status'        => 'publish',
    'showposts'          => intval( get_anolox_option_by('an_homep_count', 3)),
    'paged'              => $paged,
    'tax_query'          => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category',
        'terms' => 19,      
        'field' => 'id',
        'operator' => 'NOT IN' 
    )
);
```

Comment: I tried it but instead of excluding category it displays post from accessories category only, what i want is to exclude posts from 'accessories' category from being displayed

Comment: I tried that code but it didn't work, it still showed posts from the accessories category.. i updated my post with the code i used based on what you gave me

Comment: I've made another update that may solve it.  Now the query is directly checking the `id` of the custom taxonomy rather than the `slug`.

Comment: still didn't work.. :( just incase here's the custom post type code: http://pastebin.com/xZ8cEzGjand the actual page: http://pastebin.com/fjJagyyU wherein i place the loop, i'm not sure why it doesn't work, from how I understand the code you gave, it should work.

Comment: boo ... sorry, but I'm all out of ideas :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be a layer of nesting.  Try changing

```
    $args=array(
    'post_type'          => 'items'
    'post_status'        => 'publish',
    'showposts'          => intval( get_anolox_option_by('an_homep_count', 3)),
    'paged'              => $paged,
    'tax_query'          => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category',
        'terms' => 19,      
        'field' => 'id',
        'operator' => 'NOT IN' 
    )
);
```

To:

```
    $args=array(
    'post_type'          => 'items'
    'post_status'        => 'publish',
    'showposts'          => intval( get_anolox_option_by('an_homep_count', 3)),
    'paged'              => $paged,
    'tax_query'          => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category',
            'terms' => 19,      
            'field' => 'id',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN' 
        )
    )
);
```

This worked for me. :-/